# How is composed "public host key and certificates (K_S)" in SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY message? (SSH2 key exchange)

Tags: java, ssh

I'm trying to implement SSH2 key exchange in Java, and having some difficulties. The [RFC4419](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4419) states, that:

> The server responds with:
>
> ```
>  byte    SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
>  string  server public host key and certificates (K_S)
>  mpint   f
>  string  signature of H
> ```

My question is - how the "server public host key and certificates (K_S)" should be composed? Where can I find this information?

I have host public and private key, and can read all information needed like for example:

```
/*
 Read the required variables from the public key.
 */
DSAParams pubKeyDSAParams = ((DSAPublicKey) pair.getPublic()).getParams();
BigInteger p = pubKeyDSAParams.getP();
BigInteger q = pubKeyDSAParams.getQ();
BigInteger g = pubKeyDSAParams.getG();

/*
Read the private exponent from the private key.
 */
DSAPrivateKey privKey = (DSAPrivateKey) pair.getPrivate();
BigInteger x = privKey.getX();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself in [RFC4253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt):

> Signatures are encoded as follows:
>
> ```
>   string    signature format identifier (as specified by the
>             public key/certificate format)
>   byte[n]   signature blob in format specific encoding.
> ```
>
> The "ssh-dss" key format has the following specific encoding:
>
> ```
>   string    "ssh-dss"
>   mpint     p
>   mpint     q
>   mpint     g
>   mpint     y
> ```
>
> Here, the 'p', 'q', 'g', and 'y' parameters form the signature key 
>   blob.

Signature formats:

> The following public key and/or certificate formats are currently
>          defined:
>
> ```
>    ssh-dss           REQUIRED     sign   Raw DSS Key
>    ssh-rsa           RECOMMENDED  sign   Raw RSA Key
>    pgp-sign-rsa      OPTIONAL     sign   OpenPGP certificates (RSA key)
>    pgp-sign-dss      OPTIONAL     sign   OpenPGP certificates (DSS key)
> ```